# Visualizing my computer's internals

Tags: linux, 3d, hardware

I'm looking for an app/utility that shows me a 3-Dimensional, navigable/manipulable view of my physical computer - based on hardware information it either obtains itself, or that I provide it using another utility (like `lshw` or `inxi`).

Required features:

- Gratis or extremely cheap.
- Runs on x86_64.
- Runs on Linux (with X).

Desired features:

- Gratis.
- Open-source with a decent license.
- Actively maintained (otherwise it won't work with newer hardware)
- Lets you take hardware apart (i.e. "install" and "remove" pieces of hardware) in the visualization, to inspect it separately.
- Supports navigation, rotation, opening sides of the case etc.

Comment: I'm curious: what's the final purpose of having such a program?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke: 1. Educational. 2. Deciding whether my PC can fit another piece of hardware of some kind.

Comment: Desktop only, or laptop too?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: Desktop-only is better than nothing of course. Also, laptops would be much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm not sure my solution fully meets your criteria there does exist a game called 'PC Building Simulator' on steam (of which steam can be installed on linux somewhat).

There is also an associated discord server and community behind the game.